# Incompatible pointer type 'uint8_t *' send to 'uint8_t **' - How can it be fixed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, buffer, nsstream, nsinputstream

I get the warning

> Incompatable ponter type 'uint8_t *' send to 'uint8_t **'

when passing value to parameter 'buffer' in below method in NSStream class

```
- (BOOL)getBuffer:(uint8_t **)buffer length:(NSUInteger *)len;
```

Below is the code I am using. 'fileStream' is 'NSInputStream' instant object

```
    uint8_t oneByte;
[fileStream read: &oneByte maxLength: 1];
NSUInteger* remaining = 0;
[fileStream getBuffer: &oneByte length:remaining];
```

Comment: tried `uint8_t *oneByte;`? :)

Comment: While using *oneByte operation failed in below method 
- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len .
My code
    uint8_t *oneByte = NULL;
    [fileStream read: oneByte maxLength: 1];
(using &oneByte gives warning now. So used oneByte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the signature that the method does not want you to allocate space for the buffer, or pass the length: it will return a pointer to an existing buffer, and set the length of that buffer to the `NSUInteger` pointer that you pass, like this:

```
uint8_t *buf;
NSUInteger len;
[fileStream getBuffer:&buf length:&len];
```

Comment: While using *oneByte operation failed in below method 
- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len

My code
    uint8_t *oneByte = NULL;
    [fileStream read: oneByte maxLength: 1];
(using &oneByte gives warning now. So used oneByte)

Comment: @AfsalMeerakutty The `read:maxLength:` method has a different signature than `getBuffer:length:`. You shouldn't be using the same parameters in these two calls - the first one needs you to allocate a buffer, while the second one gives the buffer back to you.

Comment: thank you dasblinkenlight. I misunderstood the method to get length of buffer already read by the read method. How can I get remaining data from stream after reading part of it? I want to know this because currently - (BOOL)hasBytesAvailable in NSInputSream is returning me false after reading 112th line in my text file

Comment: @AfsalM The most common approach is to call `read:maxLength:` method in a loop until it returns zero. Since this is a file stream, it wouldn't block when no data is available (that's more useful for socket streams).